# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).velocity is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, browserify, velocity, commonjs

I have the following code:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
var velocity = require('velocity-animate');

module.exports = function () {

    function togglePanel () {

        $('.trip-assist-search-panel__container').velocity({
            height: '0px'
        },{
            duration: 400
        });

    }

    return {
        togglePanel: togglePanel
    };

}();
```

When `togglePanel()` gets triggered, the following error gets thrown:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).velocity is not a function

Which is usually solved by making sure you're loading JQuery before a library that requires it. But, I am..

```
var $ = require('jquery'); // first
var velocity = require('velocity-animate'); // second
```

So.. what gives?

Comment: I don't get why you assign jQuery to a local var and not globaly - only globaly velocity can use it.
I also don't get why you assign the requirement of velocity to a local variable as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://julian.com/research/velocity/):

> **Module Loader: Browserify**
>  If you're using Velocity with jQuery, you must require jQuery before Velocity, and you must assign
>   jQuery globally on the window object:
>
> ```
> window.jQuery = window.$ = require("path/to/jquery-x.x.x.js");
> require("path/to/velocity.js");
> // Optional: If you're using the UI pack, require it after Velocity. (You don't need to assign it to a variable.)
> require("path/to/velocity.ui.js");
> /* Your app code here. */
> $("body").velocity({ opacity: 0.5 });
> ```

You've only assigned jQuery to a *local* `$` variable.